# *** glibc detected *** ./main: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x08857008 ***

Tags: c++, linux

Line of fail: **Xplano.ubicacion(Eureca.getCoordenadaX(),Eureca.getCoordenadaY())** 
Location in main.cpp, down  but most information in the source code.

Thanks.

> Error: *** glibc detected**  ./main: double free or corruption
>   (fasttop): 0x08857008 **
>   ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x70f01)[0xb7550f01]
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x72768)[0xb7552768]
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb755581d]
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(*ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb76d44bf]
>   ./main[0x8048cec]
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(*_libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb74f6e46]
>   ./main[0x8048941]
>   ======= Memory map: ======== 08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 165215     /home/administrator/Taller/main 0804a000-0804b000 rw-p
>   00001000 08:05 165215     /home/administrator/Taller/main
>   08857000-08878000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
>   b7300000-b7321000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  b7321000-b7400000 ---p
>   00000000 00:00 0  b74de000-b74e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   b74e0000-b763c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 914371
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.13.so b763c000-b763d000 ---p
>   0015c000 08:05 914371     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.13.so
>   b763d000-b763f000 r--p 0015c000 08:05 914371
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.13.so b763f000-b7640000 rw-p
>   0015e000 08:05 914371     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.13.so
>   b7640000-b7643000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  b7643000-b765f000 r-xp
>   00000000 08:05 914451     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>   b765f000-b7660000 rw-p 0001b000 08:05 914451
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 b7660000-b7661000 rw-p 00000000
>   00:00 0  b7661000-b7685000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 914379
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm-2.13.so b7685000-b7686000 r--p
>   00023000 08:05 914379     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm-2.13.so
>   b7686000-b7687000 rw-p 00024000 08:05 914379
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm-2.13.so b7687000-b7767000 r-xp
>   00000000 08:05 528279     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
>   b7767000-b776b000 r--p 000e0000 08:05 528279
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17 b776b000-b776c000 rw-p
>   000e4000 08:05 528279     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
>   b776c000-b7773000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  b7788000-b778c000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  b778c000-b778d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vdso] b778d000-b77a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 914407
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so b77a9000-b77aa000 r--p 0001b000 08:05
>   914407     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so b77aa000-b77ab000 rw-p
>   0001c000 08:05 914407     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
>   bfe46000-bfe67000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack] Aborted

Main.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Coordenada.cpp"
#include "plano.cpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main (){
 int x;
 int y;
 x = y = 0;


    std::cout << "Digite la Coordenada X:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Digite la Coordenada Y:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> y;
    Coordenada Eureca;
    Plano Xplano;
    Eureca.setCoordenadaX(x);
    Eureca.setCoordenadaY(y);
    std::cout << "X es: " << Eureca.getCoordenadaX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Y es: " << Eureca.getCoordenadaY() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Ubicado en el " << Xplano.ubicacion(Eureca.getCoordenadaX(),Eureca.getCoordenadaY()) << std::endl;
    Eureca.~Coordenada();
    Xplano.~Plano();

    return 0;
}
```

Plano.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "plano.hpp"

using namespace std;
using std::string;

    Plano::Plano(){ubicacionX = "desconocido";}
    Plano::~Plano(){}



    string Plano::ubicacion(int x, int y) { if ((x=0) && (y=0)){this->ubicacionX = "origen";}
                                            return (this->ubicacionX);}
```

Plano.HPP

```
#ifndef _PLANO_HPP
#define _PLANO_HPP
#include <string>
using std::string;
class Plano{
    private:
       string ubicacionX;
    public:
        Plano();
        ~Plano();
        string ubicacion(int x, int y);
    };
#endif
```

Comment: Meet http://valgrind.org/.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Before asking a question, please read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to call object destructor explicitly. When objects go out of scope, their destructors will be called implicitly. You need to remove below two lines of code:

```
// Eureca.~Coordenada();
// Xplano.~Plano();
```